# Grails3 Webflow - Is there any working example?

Tags: grails, grails-webflow

I am currently working with grails trying to setup a webflow. I used this (quite) old example: 
https://github.com/grails-samples/book-flow

When I run my grails app and want to start the flow, I just get the error:

> Error: Page Not Found (404)
>   Path: /book/shoppingCart

Is this example app outdated? Can someone give me a hint to setup a simple webflow with grails?
Thanks

Comment: You need to add this plugin in buildConfig.groovy: https://grails.org/plugin/webflow . There is a docs: https://grails.org/plugin/webflow it should be more helpful than example

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am using grails3, so I do not have a buildConfig.groovy but instead a build.gradle. I guess I should put that plugin here. But I cannot find any documentation where?!

Comment: As I know difference should be only in buildConfig.groovy. All code should be simple.